# Rear view mirror button glue is still on glass

Tags: windshield, mirrors

I see most of the answers or questions have been to remove the button from the glass when your rear view mirror falls off my button is still attached to my rear view mirror but the thick glue is still on my windshield cannot find a way to get it off anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you try a razor blade?

Comment: For this use, a single-edged razor blade is far preferable to a double-edged one.